# How to get only 'date' from datetime class

Tags: php, datetime

I have Datetime object which has '2013-01-22 13:23:43'

I would like to pick up only 2013-01-22 and get it back to Datetime class.

I think I can

```
$newdatetime = new DateTime($datetime->format('Y-m-d'));
```

but it looks bit a clumsy.

Do you have any idea??

Comment: Why on earth would you wrap it back in a datetime class? What are you trying to do? I.e. what is the end goal and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

**Do your processing with a DateTime object, and the output with whatever format you want**.

Meaning, you **shouldn't pass the single date back to a new DateTime object**.

Instead, you should work with a normal DateTime object (you can ignore the time if it isn't important to you), and then, after you finish working with it, simply format it, like so:

```
$date = new DateTime('can haz date plz');

/* Do some processing here using $date */

$date->format("Y-m-d"); //See? No time!
```

Don't start objects you don't need. If you don't need the time in the DateTime object, simply ignore it.

If you **must** remove the time, you may use the [`DateTime::setTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) method:

```
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks setTime() is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime class construct expects a date/time string as first argument and [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) as second argument. You have to use the format function to format date. See more info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). If you need the copy of the same datetime object you can use [clone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php), see example below:

```
$objDateTime = new DateTime('2013-01-22 13:23:43');
$newObj = clone $objDateTime;
echo $newObj->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following, it may help

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

OR

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($somedate)); // $somedate = '2013-01-22 13:23:43'
```

Comment: What is it with using unix timestamps as answers to questions about DateTime objects?

Answer (score -2):

`$jobdate  = 2013-01-22 13:23:43;
$pieces = explode(" ", $jobdate);
$pieces[0]; // 2013-01-22
 $pieces[1]; // 13:23:43`